# Hyperlink on <li> inside gridview onclick call function server side

Tags: c#, gridview, hyperlink

I have created a grid view and in one cell I show a list of bullet point and I want to put for each bullet point a hyperlink which call a function on side server with parameter this is the code

```
string vulns =  "<p>Number of samples: " + array.listvulns.Count + ".</p><ul>";
            foreach (Vuln vl in array.listvulns)
            {
                string callfunction = "runat=\"server\"  OnClick=\"openSolution(\"" + vl.idvuln + "\",\"" + NBName + "\")\"";
                vulns+= "<li  >" + vl.Description.Replace('\'',' ') + " Risk level : " + vl.risk +  "</li>" + Environment.NewLine + "\r\n\n\r<br/>";

            }

            vulns+="</ul>";
```

and in the aspx file I have done this itemtemplate

```
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <HeaderTemplate>Vulns</HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%# Eval("Vulns") %>

                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

I can see the list but the link doesn't work

thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please modify code as below

```
vulns+= "<li><a OnClick=\"openSolution(\"" + vl.idvuln + "\",\"" + NBName + "\")\"">" + vl.Description.Replace('\'',' ') + " Risk level : " + vl.risk +  "</a></li>" + Environment.NewLine + "\r\n\n\r<br/>";
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the result is better but the EVAL function give me this   '<a 445","test")"="" onclick="openSolution(">SNP vun. Risk level : 6</a>'